# jUnit testing Database operations

Tags: android, sqlite, junit3

I'm developing an Android application with database storage.

I want to test some classes that I use to access database.

I've found `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` to test Activities but I haven't found anything to test classes.

How can I do that? I haven't used jUnit before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use [AndroidTestCases](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html) when writing unit tests for the Android platform. They provide access to a Context instance (if required), but otherwise work like the standard JUnit test class. You may also need to look at [AndroidTestRunner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestRunner.html) to test your classes. There are some good tutorials out there; now that you know what to look for, I'm sure you can find them. Happy hunting! :D

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question a month ago, and at the end I have finished using the same classes to say in your reply.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it took this long to receive a reply on what should be an easily answerable question. Hopefully the next time you ask something you get an answer sooner!

Comment: Can someone throw up some sample code to show how to setup a test case that uses a data base?  I seem to be having Accessor Exceptions when doing so.